# How to Fetch data at the time of block production?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, consensus, block-production

Can I implement a pallet which holds the node information and at the block production time we can use this node information?

Comment: You wan to in information from the node into a pallet or the other way around extract information from a pallet into the node?

Comment: Actually I want information of the node/miner who authorise the block at the time of block authorisation. I'm thinking if i can build a pallet which contains miner/node information and we can fetch that on the block production time.

Comment: Have a look at pallet_authorship ( https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/authorship/src/lib.rs ) and the FindAuthor trait https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/bd80dcf6858a0ec9e61b5aceab933979f7258d2b/substrate/frame/support/src/traits/validation.rs#L55